# Inconsistent results when using openquery via Linked Server to Oracle Source

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I’m facing a weird issue. I’m using a linked server connection to fetch data from Oracle database from MS SQL Server.

The source table has a field of data type “LONG” and a query to fetch data from this table is returning inconsistent results in SQL Server Management Studio. I’m using MS SQL Server 2016.

When I query the table for a specific row in the source database, the query returns a simple string.

When I run then run a query that returns several rows (more than 1000 rows) of which the specific row mentioned above is also a part of it, then I’m presented with a completely different value in the field aforementioned “LONG” field.

There are no duplicates in the source database. The specific row in question is not updated in the time between running the both queries. The Linked Server used in the openquery is exactly the same. The query is run from the same server in adjacent query windows.

Is there a server setting or Linked Server setting that I need to investigate.

I have very very basic dba skills so please assume that I know nothing!

Screenshots attached for reference.[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbR93.jpg)

Comment: Maybe posting some of your query and results here may help.

Comment: Hi Jin Lee, I've added screenshots to my original query now. Thank you.